# How to do a ´subaggregation´ of a data frame in R

Tags: r

Quick question.

This is a sampler of my dataset:

```
 name  date size
999321   -5   20
999321   -5   40
999321   59   50
999321   59   50
999322   -5   32
999322   -5   45
999322   -5   20
999322   66   13
999322   66   24
999322   66   14
999322  101   24
999322  101   23
999322  101   15
```

So. I wish to ´subaggregate´ the sum of the sizes according to the `date` they belong to and in turn according to the `name` they belong to. Basically I want my dataframe to become like this:

```
name    date  size
999321   -5   80 {20+60)
999321   59   100 {50+50}
999322   -5   97 {32+45+20)
999322   66   51 {13+24+14}
999322  101   62 {24+23+15}
```

I wanted to make a loop function which aggregated `size` values according to `date` until the number of observations ran out, but the problem is that the number of observations that each subject has varies quite a lot (as you can see, subject 999321 has 4 observations (2 for each `date` value), but 999322 has 9 observations, and this happens in the whole sample of my dataset (4879 observations in total from 322 subjects).

So, how can I do this?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean 999321-->-5-->60? (20+40)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or

```
> aggregate(size ~ name + date, data=d, FUN="sum")
    name date size
1 999321   -5   60
2 999322   -5   97
3 999321   59  100
4 999322   66   51
5 999322  101   62
```

Comment: So... ran into another problem with this same dataset... the negative dates are giving me a headache.  The date variable is supposed to be the time (in days) since study start with it´s respective size measurement on that date, so the negative dates is the time before study start.  The problem I´m having is that I´m applying a growth constat equation that doesn´t allow for me to use negative ´date´ values.... so, how can I normalize the date vector where the negative values move up to +1 and the other values from the same ´subject´ move up proportionally?

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you want `do.call(rbind,by(d, d$name, function(x){x$date<-x$date-min(x$date)+1;x }))`. It converts date for each `name` to start from 1. Post a new question and link to it, if this doesn't answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `data.table` package:

```
df[, list(sum(size)), by=list(name,date)]
```

OR you can use the `sqldf` package for this:

```
sqldf("select name, date, sum(size) as size from DF group by name, date")



name date size
1 999321   -5   60
2 999321   59  100
3 999322   -5   97
4 999322   66   51
5 999322  101   62
```